# How to create a new dataframe with CSV file from a folder with subfolders in Pyspark in S3

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, pyspark

Hi I'm very new to Pyspark and S3. I have problem at hand. I have a folder, which consists of subfolders and files and also files from the subfolder(all CSVs) i need to create a new dataframe or a csv file where i get contents of the files and create as a single file. Which later need to be read to a table in postgress

Can anyone please help me. I have code in python, but not sure how to go about with pyspark and S3

Answer (score 1):

Try with this [option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader).

> recursiveFileLookup – recursively scan a directory for files. Using this option disables partition discovery.

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("recursiveFileLookup","true").csv("s3://path/to/root/")
```

Comment: Thanks, could you send me the entire sequence. I'm new to this, infact trying for the first time.